# Cisco show all static route

Tags: router, cisco

Here is the question ->
  I have added a floating static route with administrative distance 200 to a router, as default, `show ip route static` only displays one static route with the lowest administrative distance.
  Is there a command will show both static routes at once ?
  I recall, `show eigrp topology` will display all the alternatives routes with different cost at one table.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 8):

The route table only shows the live routes.

to show all statics you'll need to show what's configured:

```
show run | inc ip route
```

This is on IOS of course

Comment: On IOS-XR it can simply be `show run router static` with the optional addition of `vrf XXX` (obviously replacing XXX with the relevant VRF name)